# FlatList at the middle of the screen doesn't show full content

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Like I said above my problem is that my FlatList that is positioned on the middle of the screen and goes to the bottom is not showing the whole content of the last card that I have. Like this:

[image]

As you can see the last card is missing the image and 3 actions buttons that you can see that have the above card. So my question is what style can I give to the flatlist or if it have a property to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT
This is my code(the relevant part I think):

```
return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.topHeader}>
        <View style={styles.imageProfile}>

          {this.state.isLoaded ?
            this.props.isLogged ?
              <View>
                <View style={styles.imgContainer} style={{ alignItems: "center", marginBottom: 20 }}>
                  <Image style={styles.userImg} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50 }} source={{ uri: "data:image/png;base64," + this.state.user.picture }} />
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.name}>{this.state.user.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subheaderText}>{arrayCounters}</Text>
              </View>
              :
              <View>
                <View style={styles.imgContainer} style={{ alignItems: "center", marginBottom: 20 }}>
                  <Image style={styles.userImg} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50 }} source={require("../../assets/no-user.jpg")} />
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.logIn}>
                  <Text style={styles.subheaderText}>Iniciar sesión</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            : null}

          {!this.state.isLoaded &&
            <View style={styles.loading}>
              <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#F5DA49" />
            </View>
          }
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.tabsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeTab(1)} style={[styles.tab, this.state.tabSelected === 1 && styles.tabSelected]}>
          <Text style={styles.tabText}>PÚBLICACIONES</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeTab(2)} style={[styles.tab, this.state.tabSelected === 2 && styles.tabSelected]}>
          <Text style={styles.tabText}>FAVORITOS</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View>


 <View>
{this.state.isLoadedMyPosts && this.state.tabSelected === 2 && 
 this.state.favoritesPosts &&
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.favoritesPosts}
              renderItem={({ item, separators }) => (
                <PostItem key={item._id} item={item} isTabFavorites= 
                 {true} removedFav={this.removedFav.bind(this)} />

              )}
              keyExtractor={item => item._id}
              onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            />
        }
```

The styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  noPosts: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: "relative",
    marginTop: 50
  },
  textNoPosts: {
    marginTop: 20,
    fontSize: 20
  },
  name: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "#FFF",
    marginBottom: 5
  },
  tabText: {
    color: "#262628",
    fontSize: 20
  },
  tabsContainer: {
    width: width,
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  tab: {
    width: width / 2,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingVertical: 15
  },
  tabSelected: {
    borderBottomColor: '#F5DA49',
    borderBottomWidth: 4
  },
  loadingPosts: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 120,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  loading: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    opacity: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  topHeader: {
    backgroundColor: "#262628",
    width: width,
    height: 200
  },
  imageProfile: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 200
  },
  userImg: {
    borderRadius: 50,
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  subheaderText: {
    color: "#fff"
  },
  imgContainer: {

  }
});
```

Comment: We'll need some code to help you, it's hard to see what may be the problem here. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my question @Arnaud

Comment: If your problem comes from a styling mistake, we need your current styling

Comment: I added the markup and the styles @Arnaud

Comment: Please try to include a link that reproduces the issue with something like expo maybe. Makes it even easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole of the view in scroll view. I guess that should work